# Is anything wrong with using static readonly references for a service class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, soa

I have inherited this piece of code, and the original author for some reason really liked static readonly references.

I have outlined the general pattern below, **what ramifications does having these static readonly references have?**

```
public class DbAccess
{
    private static readonly ISomethingFactory = SomethingFactories.GetFactory("1");
    private static IThing1Dao Thing1Dao { get {return ISomethingFactory.Thing1Dao; }}
    private static IThing2Dao Thing2Dao { get {return ISomethingFactory.Thing2Dao; }}
}

public class SomethingFactories
{
   public static ISomethingFactory GetFactory(string key) 
   {
      switch(key)
      {
         case "...":
         return new SomeFactory();
      }
   }
}    

public class SomeFactory : ISomeFactory
{    
    public IThing1Dao Thing1Dao
    {
       get { return new Thing1Dao(); }
    }
}    

public class SomeService : ISomeService
{
    private static readonly IThing1Dao thing1Dao = DbAccess.Thing1Dao
    private static readonly IThing2Dao thing2Dao = DbAccess.Thing2Dao

    public Thing1Object1 GetObject1(int id)
    {
        return thing1Dao.GetObject1(id);    
    }

    public Thing1Object2 GetObject2(int id)
    {
        return thing1Dao.GetObject2(id);
    }
}
```

The usage in the .aspx pages is like:

```
public class MyBasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected static readonly SomeService someService = new SomeService();     
}    

public class SomeAspxPage : MyBasePage
{
   void btnAddObject1(...)
   {
      Thing1Object1 obj1 = someService.GetObject(1);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

*static* means that only one instance of `ISomethingFactory` exists, and that instance can be accessed through the type (not one instance per instance of `DbAccess`).

*readonly* means that, after initialization, the value cannot be overwritten.

This is a fairly normal pattern for performing initialization based on startup-time data (e.g. data from app.config).

Answer (score 3):

Web applications are multi-threaded, so static members are of limited use.

If you have a static reference to an object, the object has to be thread safe, or you have to synchronise the use of it so that only a single thread can use it at any time.

Making the static reference read-only means that the reference itself is thread safe, as it can't be changed once it's set, but that doesn't automatically make the object that it's referencing thread safe.

Comment: so there won't be any locking/serialization issues?

Comment: @user1361315: Any locking issues depends on what object you are referencing, and how you use it. If you want to serialise the property, then you have a problem as static members are not serialised, as they are not part of the object instance.